# Fast/Efficient counting of list of space delimited strings in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, counter, python-itertools, chain

Given the input:

```
x = ['foo bar', 'bar blah', 'black sheep']
```

I could do this to get the count of each word in the list of space delimited string:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(chain(*map(str.split, x)))
```

Or I could simple iterate through and get:

```
c = Counter()
for sent in x:
    for word in sent.split():
        c[word]+=1
```

[out]:

```
Counter({'bar': 2, 'sheep': 1, 'blah': 1, 'foo': 1, 'black': 1})
```

The question is **which is more efficient if the input list of string is extremely huge?** Are there other ways to achieve the same counter object?

Imagine it's a text file object that has billions of lines with 10-20 words each.

Comment: Assuming each `sent` is reasonably sized, your second solution should be about as good as you can do.  Of course you could manually iterate through the characters, but I don't see that giving any improvement.  I'm not familiar enough with chain to know how it will perform here.

Comment: Why don't you time it and see?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in Python 3x, both `chain(*map(str.split, x))` and simple iteration will create intermediate lists sequentially from each line; this will not take up much memory in either case. Performance should be very close and may be implementation-dependent.

However, it is most efficient memory-wise to create a generator function to feed Counter(). Either way you use string.split(), it creates intermediate lists which are not necessary. This could cause slowdown if you have a particularly long line, but to be honest it's unlikely.

Such a generator function is described below. Note that I am using optional typing for clarity.

```
from typing import Iterable, Generator
def gen_words(strings: Iterable[str]) -> Generator[str]:
    for string in strings:
        start = 0
        for i, char in enumerate(string):
            if char == ' ':
                if start != i:
                    yield string[start:i]
                start = i
        if start != i:
            yield string[start:i]
c = counter(gen_words(strings))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)).

Following are some profiling tools:

- print [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) in strategic places. (or use [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(Unix)))
- [cProfile](https://pymotw.com/2/profile/)
- [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler)
- [heapy](http://smira.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/heapy.html) tracks all objects inside Python’s memory (good for memory leaks)
- For long-running systems, use [dowser](http://e-mats.org/2013/01/debugging-pythons-memory-usage-with-dowser/): allows live objects introspection (web browser interface)
- [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler/0.9) for RAM usage
- examine Python bytecode with [dis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html)