# Runtime of two separate getHeight algorithms for a binary search tree

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have two separate implementations of a getHeight() method for a binary search tree (not necessarily a balanced BST though), one is iterative and one is recursive.  Here's the iterative one:

```
def height(root): #iterative approach, uses a stack for a depth first search
    max_height = 0
    myStack = [root]
    currentNode = None
    root.level = True

    while len(myStack) != 0:
        currentNode = myStack[-1]
        if currentNode.left is not None and currentNode.left.level is not True:
            myStack.append(currentNode.left)
            currentNode.left.level = True
            continue
        if currentNode.right is not None and currentNode.right.level is not True:
            myStack.append(currentNode.right)
            currentNode.right.level = True
            continue
        elif (currentNode.left is None or currentNode.left.level is True) and (currentNode.right is None or currentNode.right.level is True):
            height = len(myStack) - 1
            if height > max_height:
              max_height = height
            myStack.pop()
return max_height
```

and here's the recursive approach:

```
def recurseHeight(root):
    add = 0
    l, r = 0, 0
    if root.left is not None:
        l = 1 + recurseHeight(root.left)
    if root.right is not None:
        r = 1 + recurseHeight(root.right)

    return l if l > r else r
```

So, I know from a space-complexity perspective, the recursive algorithm is better.  However, from my understanding, the runtime of the iterative algorithm is O(n) (because it has to search all n nodes, and won't stop until that point), but I was wondering what the runtime of the recursive algorithm is.  I know I would have to use the master theorem, and part of me thinks it would also be O(n) simply because I would have to visit all the nodes no matter what, but I'm not sure.  Could anyone help find the runtime of the recursive algorithm?

(side note, I'm doing this to practice for interviews - if anyone has good problems/learning resources, don't hesitate to say them loud and proud :) )

Comment: Instead of guessing, you could just profile both approaches and learn exactly their memory and CPU usages. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43629424/1656850.
Also, welcome to the site: you may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying exactly it's O(n) as you always visit every node in the tree and visit each one only one time which means you need O(n) of work for the recursive version